# ¿Cómo hacer que un cuadrado rebote en un ángulo de 90 grados usando PYGAME?

Tags: python, pygame, game

Quiero hacer que el cuadrado, al tocar uno de los bordes, sus coordenadas variasen en un ángulo de 90 grados. Pero no consigo conseguir dicho efecto, se sale de los límites y la velocidad empieza a incrementar.

Actualmente estoy calculando cada avance con:

```
rect_x += rectxSpeed
rect_y += rectySpeed
```

Y al tocar un borde:

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=5
    rect_y=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=5
    rectx_y=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

La velocidad no cambia.

---

Si cambio el codigo de tocar un borde a:

```
 if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

Se incrementa la velocidad continuamente.

---

¿Cómo puedo calcular correctamente un rebote de 90 grados?

Este es el código completo:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
rect_x= 50.0
rect_y = 50.0
rectxSpeed=5
rectySpeed=5

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here

    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    string=str(rect_x)
    string2=str(rect_y)
    string3="["+string+"]"+"["+string2+"]"
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text = font.render(string3,True,RED)
    screen.blit(text, [0, 0])    
    #Main rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [rect_x, rect_y, 50, 50]) 
    #Second rectangle inside the rectangle 1
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rect_x+10, rect_y+10, 30, 30])  
    rect_x += rectxSpeed
    rect_y+=rectySpeed
    if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
        rectySpeed=5
        rect_y=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)
    if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
        rectxSpeed=5
        rect_x=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

---

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=5
    rect_y=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=5
    rectx_y=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

Da como resultado

[image: Video del comportamiento actual]

---

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed=rectySpeed*-(math.pi/2)

   if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed=rectxSpeed*-(math.pi/2)
```

Da como resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te das cuenta de que en ningún momento estás cambiando la velocidad, no? Solamente estás reemplazando las posiciones en x e y, pero no la nueva velocidad, que por ejemplo debería ser negativa luego de determinados rebotes

Comment: Probé a variar la velocidad, pero se incrementa continuamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu ejemplo, en el que la velocidad de desplazamiento inicial en ambos ejes es la misma para obtener un rebote de 90º basta con invertir el signo de la velocidad del eje cuyo límite es alcanzado:

```
if rect_y>450 or rect_y<0:
    rectySpeed*=-1

if rect_x>650 or rect_x<0:
    rectxSpeed*=-1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]